Laravel Jetstream remembers email verification after deleting the account
Larael 11.10.0, Ubuntu 24.04.
I'm testing the Jetstream email verification feature for registration.
I just setup my .env database and email section in order to match my configuration.
The code is the default one after creating a new project. I enabled the verification feature in User.php:
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail

Here the step to reproduce the issue:

open http://127.0.0.1:8000 and click on Register
fill the form and submit
wait for the activation email and click on the link
login and open the profile settings
DELETE the account
register again with the same email

I'm expecting the activation email is sent as usual, instead it shows the "Resend email" dialog:

Why (and where) it remembers the deleted account email?
It's not browser's side (i.e. cookies) because I deleted them.
I checked in the database (table Users) and the table is empty.
How to avoid this odd behavior?
